# Best way to migrate Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, upgrade

I read online that it can be achieved with

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

However I tried that and thought that the amount time spent on it will be more than what I have.

Instead I thought about creating a new instance, then basically reinstalling the services / copying the missing from the old server to it and then deleting the old one.

WDYT? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Install new OS and migrate data, if its an option - is almost always the best way to go, as it cleans out the cruft and has the fewest curve balls. can also be far quicker. Unfortunately in very customised environments this can look unattractive due to specifics of the old system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option One (clone server and upgrade, likely easiest)

1. Create an AMI of your server (Google how to do this, it's easy but has a few steps)
2. Create a new server based on the AMI
3. Upgrade the server

Option Two (new server, migrate data)

1. Create a new server
2. Install software, migrate daya

Comment: Thanks, but that's understandable that there are these two options. And I actually did create a snapshot (which is a must and I think it's what's basically AMI is, right?). The real problem is to decide - whether to upgrade from 14.04 -> 16.04 -> 18.04 with all the struggling in mind, or just installing a new server and then replicating the data (in my case there's not a crazy amount of). Or maybe there's a third unknown to me option, and that's why I was aksing. EDIT: I see what you mean, so AMI in this case is not a snapshot, but an actual server so I can upgrade it and not stopping the old.

Comment: An AMI is basically a snapshot with some metadata to let you create a new server based on that snapshot / existing server. There may be other options, but those are the two major ones. I would probably try the upgrade on a cloned server first, if it worked fine I'd keep it. If you can easily set up a new server, eg if you have infrastructure as code or it's simple, a new server may be cleaner.